# How to prevent Sublime Text to change the rights on a file?

Tags: linux, sublimetext2, rights-management

when i take control on a file with Sublime Text (with the right to write), i become the new owner when i save. I don't want it.

Could you tell me what i've to do to prevent this ?

Best regards

Comment: Did you consider using a version control system like [git](http://git-scm.com/) ?

Comment: This is clearly not a programming question.

Comment: File a bug with Sublime developers.

Answer (score 0):

I've added

```
"atomic_save": false
```

in my User Settings, and it seems to be ok.

Hope it's a correct issue.